# Slider на c#, как поставить начальное значение?

Tags: c#, slider

У меня есть обычный слайдер и нужно сделать так, что бы при запуски приложения он принимал нулевое значение, но по умолчанию оно стоит максимальное, как это можно исправить?
Т.е. при запуски приложения он такой:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а должен быть такой:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Думал, что в свойствах есть что-нибудь типа `StartValue`, но нет.

---

Нашел, что надо, ну почти. Для WPF:
В XAML:

```
<Slider Value="0" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" SelectionStart="0" Height="30" 
        IsSelectionRangeEnabled="True" ValueChanged="Slider_ValueChanged" />
```

В коде:

```
private void Slider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    ((Slider)sender).SelectionEnd=e.NewValue;
}
```

Собственно **IsSelectionRangeEnabled**: задает затенение участка ползунка. Если оно установлено в True, то начальная и конечная отметка затенения задаются с помощью свойств **SelectionStart** и **SelectionEnd.** Это то, что мне надо было, но это в WPF, а вот как теперь тоже самое сделать, только для Windows Phone?

Comment: WinForms или WPF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для WPF в XAML:

```
<code> 
    <Slider Minimum = 0
        Maximum = 100
        Value = 50 /> 
</code>
```

Minimum - минимальное значение, Maximum - соответственно максимальное, Value - стартовое значение при инициализации. Соответственно с этими параметрами можно пользоваться механизмом байндинга.

В windows forms Slider называется TrackBar и имеет теже поля для управления им (Minimum, Maximum, Value).

Вот пример Slider-a из моего приложения:

```
<Slider Grid.Column="1"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                BorderBrush="Black"
                BorderThickness="1"
                Maximum="{Binding Path=ModelMainWindow.SliderMaximum}"
                Minimum="{Binding Path=ModelMainWindow.SliderMinimum}"
                Thumb.DragCompleted="Slider_DragCompleted"
                Thumb.DragStarted="Slider_DragStarted"
                Value="{Binding Path=ModelMainWindow.SliderValue,
                                Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Это в модели:

```
        /// <summary>
    /// Represent minimum slider position
    /// </summary>
    public double SliderMinimum
    {
        get
        {
            return _sliderMinimum;
        }
        set
        {
            _sliderMinimum = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Represent maximum slider position
    /// </summary>
    public double SliderMaximum
    {
        get
        {
            return _sliderMaximum;
        }
        set
        {
            _sliderMaximum = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }        
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Represent current slider position
    /// </summary>
    public double SliderValue
    {
        get
        {
            return _sliderValue;
        }
        set
        {
            _sliderValue = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

Это класс, который реализует INPC(INotifyPropertyChanged) интерфейс:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MP3_Player.Model
{
public class BaseModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string    propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new   PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
}
```

От него я уже наследую свою модель, где и использую реализацию этого интерфейса

Comment: Я делал так, но ничего не меняется.

Comment: Если вы программируюте на WPF, то нужно, чтобы Ваши привязанные (binding) значения обязательно были или dependencyproperty или модель (или вьюмодель) реализовала интерфейс INotifyPropertyChanged и использовала его в своих свойствах. (Вызов метода RaisePropertyChanged() или NotifyPropertyChanged(), по разному можно назвать, после присвоения свойству новых значений).

Если сразу при инициализации ничего не меняется - посмотрите, возможно какая-то Ваша переменная, привязанная к полю Slider-a переопределяется?

Comment: хорошо, щас попробую похимичить)

Comment: Я добавил примеры в ответ, можете посмотреть там, как это сделано у меня.

Comment: Может я не так объяснил или может я не то делаю. 
Я попытался сделать также, как у вас, но у меня ничего дельного из этого не вышло. Пробовал всяко там "химичить", но тоже толку ноль. Я еще раз попробую объяснить, что мне нужно, может я просто не правильно свою мысль выразил. И так, как только я запускаю приложения у меня сразу появляется этот Slider и ползунок находится в правом конце и вся полоска состояния тоже закрашена, а нужно чтобы при запуски приложения этот ползунок был в левой части Slider'a, как будто начало трека только. Как-то так.

Comment: Когда я нажимаю на воспроизведение музыки, то все работает как надо. Ползунок начинает "ползти" слева направо и строка состояния в не за крашеном виде

Comment: Инициализируйте оба поля, отвечающих за минимальную и максимальную позицию, привязанных до слайдера, у меня например они инициализированы как 0 и 100, что не мешает им во время работы программы изменить свои значения на нужные мне. Если Вы делаете как в моем при мере, то скорее всего дело в этом.
Я просто сейчас тоже заметил, что в моем приложении ползунок с самого начала стоял в конце, а когда инициализировал поле, отвечающие за максимальный интервал слайдера - все стало как нужно.